# Modal content is not displayed in React Modal

Tags: reactjs

In my react application, I created a modal.

// COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Modal extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
        return nextProps.show !== this.props.show || nextProps.children !== this.props.children;
    }

    render () { 
        return (
         <div>
            <div
               className='modal'
               style={{
                  transform: this.props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                  opacity: this.props.show ? '1' : '0'
               }}>
               {this.props.children}
            </div>
         </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Modal;
```

When I call it in a main screen like this, the content is not displayed.

// MAIN SCREEN

```
<Modal show={true} modalClosed={() => alert('Modal Close') }>
   <h1>Testing Modal</h1>  
</Modal>
```

Why is this not working? h1 tag content is not displayed here.

Comment: You are missing the closing `)` in the `alert('Modal Close'` is this just a typo in your question?

Comment: Fixed it. Still doesn't work